# Unable to install MiKTeX distribution in Windows

Tags: miktex, windows

I have a fresh Windows 10 operating system installed. I am unable to install the MiKTeX 2.9 latest update in Windows. I got the following at the end of the log file after failed installation process:

```
updating package definition directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tpm\packages")...
installed 3066 package definition files
visiting repository C:\Users\HARIKR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\mik77723...
repository type: local package repository
loading lightweight database...
"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64\initexmf.exe" --common-install="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9" --set-config-value=[Core]SharedSetup=1 --admin --log-file="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\uninst.log" --verbose:
log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger (initexmf).
log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly.

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

An error occurred:
  source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\Process.cpp
  source line: 159
  message: The executed process did not succeed.
  info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64\initexmf.exe", arguments="--common-install="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9" --set-config-value=[Core]SharedSetup=1 --admin --log-file="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\uninst.log" --verbose", exitCode="1"
```

I have tried uninstalling Adobe Reader, turned off antivirus.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! If I understand well, you had a previous installation that you want to update?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of MikTeX please install Texlive 2017 which contain complete Latex packages can install both in windows and linux system

http://ctan.imsc.res.in/systems/texlive/Images/texlive2017.iso